# Cookies not in header when file requested by import

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies, chromium, es6-modules

When I request my file like in the given code example (ES6 import) either using chromium or firefox I get the corresponding request on the server-side but as opposed to the "normal" script load (by script tag with src) cookies are not provided in the header, is that normal? And if so: How am I supposed to relate this request to a session if I have cookie based authentication?

Does not work - Because Browser does not send established cookie with the request:

```
<script type="module">
  import '/index.js';
</script>
```

Works - Browser sends cookie with the request:

```
<script src="/index.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

You have to add the "crossorigin" attribute to the script tag:

```
<script type="module" crossorigin>
  import '/index.js';
</script>
```

This is because es6 module import somehow goes under CORS even if the request for the module script goes to same-origin. And CORS does not send credentials for module script requests. ...Unless you put the crossorigin attribute.

This article of Jack Archibald helped me a lot (The browser issues mentioned naturally aren't quite up to date anymore):

https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

Comment: this answer deserves more rep

Comment: This helped me a lot today, although in my case 'crossorigin' alone was not enough, but 'crossorigin="use-credentials"' was needed, even though the loaded script was same-origin. Just in case somebody has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the cookies on the window to make it visible, otherwise the browser only sends headers with requests. Something like...

`const window.cookie = document.cookie;`

Comment: I have done as you proposed and made sure the cookies are on the window object before the request for index.js went out. But the request when it arrived on the server still did not have the session cookie on it :(

Comment: Are you using angular or something of the sort?

Comment: no, all I have on the client-side is jquery and modles flag enabled, server-side I have node.js

Comment: Just wanted to say that I'm still struggling here. How can I make sure the browser sends established cookies with the header (as he normally does) when requesting the file to import from the server?