# How to serve ES6 modules on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, safari, es6-modules

I have a question regarding the usage of ES6 modules within Safari. It's driving me crazy because it prevents me from sharing my website with Safari users.

My web application and the coming up MWE **work perfectly fine** in the following environments:

- Windows: Chrome, Edge and Firefox both via a Windows local server (WAMP) and via my web server;
- Mobile: Chrome, Firefox (both in Android and iOS). Even Samsung Mobile and Opera for Android work fine.
- MacOS:

  - on **Safari**, Chrome and Firefox **via a Mac local server** (AMPPS);
  - on Chrome and Firefox via my web server.

However, my web application **does not work within MacOS Safari via my web server** (at the moment I'm trying this code on Safari 13.0.4, but all modern versions of the mentioned browsers behave the same way with respect to this problem). Similarly, it does not work within the latest version of iOS Safari.

**MWE**

*./test_class.js*

```js
export class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Created a test class");
  }
}
```

*./index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type="module">
  console.log("Starting the main script.");

  // The following line seems to cause an error in Safari only
  import { TestClass } from './test_class.js';

  // The rest is not executed due to the error
  let test_class = new TestClass;
  console.log("Done.");
</script>
```

**Console Output**

When I load *index.html* from my server, Safari's console gives me the error

> TypeError: 'text/html' is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.

**Additional info (not sure if it's relevant)**

When I go to the resource section of Safari, there is indeed an entry for *test_class.js* that does not contain the code above but instead:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>

    <script>
      function toNumbers(d)
        // ...
      function toHex()
        // ...
      var a = toNumbers("..."),
          b = toNumbers("..."),
          c = toNumbers("...");
      document.cookie = "...";

      location.href="http://www.my_super_website.com/test_class.js?i=1";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This only occurs when I connect to my server. Does the line `location.href="http://www.my_super_website.com/test_class.js?i=1";` make sense? My understanding is that at this point Safari tries to load *test_class.js* but has some issue with it.

**What I've tried so far**

- If I remove the line `import { TestClass } from './test_class.js';`, everything works fine.
- The same problem occurs if I place the `import` call within a new script file that is then used in the html document.
- I verified that my way of naming the file *./test_class.js* is correct, but since this works in most browsers I guess it's fine.
- I'm using a free-hosting solution, infinityfree.net, so maybe there's something going on there?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at popular tools like Babel, Webpack, Rollup, or Parcel to transpile and bundle your ES6 code to something that every browser would be able to use/parse?

Comment: I have not, I'm new to web development so I have no experience with these. Since all modern browsers including Safari are compatible with ES6 modules, I still think this is a good way for me to code in a organized way. But if nobody knows how to fix the issue, I'll look into these tools! Thanks :)

Comment: Hey - any progress on this in the past 6 weeks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In web development we develop using ES6 and ES7 but those are not supported yet in all browsers.

In order to ship the working code in most browsers **(Safari - Chrome - IE9 )**

and does not matter the browser. You supposed to use a build process like **( webpack - gulp - grant )** or using existing libraries like *( React, Angular and VUE )*

Example: For starting using **webpack** 
https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

witch will grant you get a complete working code by converting all your code into ES5 and bundle that code to ensure reducing chuck sizes

Comment: Thank you very much! If nobody knows what the issue is here, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: That's not an answer, because the module feature is supported from safari 12

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution:

Change your file extension from `.js` to `.mjs`. You may also need to update your server's mime types/extension association. I'm using `apache2` - I needed to go into `/etc/mime.types` and modify the line listing `js` to also contain `mjs` (so it'll now consider it to be an `application/javascript`.)

I had the simplest of tests just work - I'll need to test my website some more on Safari to verify that it now works equally well across all intended browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As only Safari is affected, the server simply delivering the wrong MIME type for '.js' files doesn't seem to be the case here. I'd therefore like to add that there is one frequent other situation where one gets this message about a wrong MIME type, and where the behavior is only at first sight browser-independent:

The server might give a reply of the sort "not found" (404) or "access denied" (403) or similar. These responses are usually given as "text/html", so that one gets the browser's somewhat misleading complaint about the wrong mime-type. The browser-dependency comes into the game when the website requires a cookie for authentification. Some former Safari versions did not sent the authentification cookie automatically when loading es6 modules from the same site, and thus these Safari versions get the 403 answer. I'm not saying that this is necessarily the case here, but it could be the case. If so, then there is a solution described at [this SO answer about missing cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737079/cookies-not-in-header-when-file-requested-by-import#45938312).